# Массив объектов классов-наследников C++

Tags: c++

Есть базовый класс. У него есть несколько наследников. Они наследуют числовые поля либо методы, возвращающий числовые значения. Надо создать объекты классов-наследников. А затем выполнять с ними операции, такие как сортировка или нахождение максимального и т.д. Причем операции выполнять по одному из полей. Причем не своим кодом, а используя интерфейс внешних библиотек. Как сделать такую коллекцию объектов различных классов?

Comment: сделать коллекцию родительских компонентов? а она спокойно примет наследников. Если все методы определены верно, то все будет работать.

Правда вопрос сформирован как то очень туманно.

Comment: Родительский класс абстрактный.

Comment: Делайте коллекцию указателей типа указатель на родительский класс. Если объекты создаются в куче, лучше использовать контейнеры из boost::ptr_containers.

Comment: в массиве хранить указатели базового класса...

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте массив указателей на базовый класс:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> a;
a.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>());
```

Comment: Я бы поменял на make_unique, т.к. в случае, если emplace_back выкинет исключение, наш объект утечет.

Answer (score 0):

Про хранение уже написали, теперь про поиск и сортировку с использованием стандартных алгоритмов. Для этого осваивайте std::bind (примеры можно искать и по boost::bind, поскольку в стандарте оно только с C++11)